# Not Found: /api/img/grid.png "GET /api/img/grid.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2468

Tags: json, django, api, get

Currently working on APIs using Django on VScode. Apis work fine, but every single time I access the urls this gets sent back to me.

Didn't really try anything yet. I feel like there is a simple solution, but still beyond my abilities to find the problem. I have no images. I don't look to load images. Just working on some basic JSON apis using rest_framework. Debug tool shows nothing because the server runs fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The issue of [12/Mar/2023 04:58:42] "GET /api/img/grid.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3455"
was resolved by shutting off a dark-mode extension called, "Dark Reader" in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Please provide enough context/code so that turns out to be useful for the community if some else faces the same issue.